# How can one publish older tags on dockerhub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-tag

How can one publish older github tags on dockerhub?
I am not seeing any info on this in their documentation.

This is needed if you move a project from one organization to another.
For example if the first org has a typo in it or if the owning org has changed.

Answer (score -1):

One can do this by manually creating a build rule for the old tag.

- go to build
- click configure automatic builds
- add a build rule by clicking on the +
- set source_type to tag
- set both source and docker tag to your tag, like 1.0.0
- click save and build
- trigger the rule if it does not build
- repeat those steps for all of your old tags